# stop the manually set location of component from changing back according to the used layout after resizing the frame

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a Jframe that contains some buttons and a main Jpanel that contains some other Jpanels, the layout of the frame is free design and the layout of the main panel is grid bag layout.

What my program does is: moving panels that are inside the main panel from a column to another after clicking on a button.
 To do that, I change the location of the panels manually using jpanel.setLocation(x,y).

The program works just fine, but when I resize the frame the panels return to their original locations as specified by the grid bag layout used. I don't want that to happen in my program.

I figured that if I use the null layout, I can solve this problem and get the result that I want. 
But I want to do it using the layouts that I specified earlier. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Layout out components in a container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) - Changing the column position could be achieved with a `GridBagLayout`, but would take some effort

Comment: MadProgrammer , Thank you for the link, but i don't think i can do it, as some panels take the space of two columns. and i simplified my problem a bit, because i don't change it from column to column only. it could be from row to row, and that will complicate things. But if there is no other (more simple) solution, i will have to try your suggestion.

Comment: `GridBagLayout` allows you specify column spanning as well - No solution would be "simple", but at least this way you're not re-inveting the wheel and working within the API

Comment: i do know that GridBagLayout can specify column spanning, it is just that i need the panel to occupy two columns of the grid. If there is no simple solution as you say. I will have no other choice but to do it the way you suggested. Thank you again for your help.